# Reading data into R from google drive

Tags: r

I am trying to read some data from google drive using R. I have seen this library called `googledrive`. With the `drive_get` I know I can pass the url or using `drive_find` I can search for a pattern . The issue I have is I will get a new csv file with slight name change(appended date in the file name). So how can I read the latest file only from that particualar drive path. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method would be to use the desktop app to sync the files to your hard drive and import it from there. This saves the trouble of authentication etc.

Importing only the latest file based on the name depends on the naming convention used. If the date was formatted as yyyy/mm/dd you could use something like:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- list.files('drive_path') %>% sort(decreasing = T)
df <- read_csv(x[1])
```